# JRE_HOME not found on pip jnius installation

Tags: python, sikuli, pyjnius

Trying to install `jnius` from pip (it is a requirement to `pip install sikuli`).

This is the error I get when I am trying to install:

[image]

Are the variables correctly defined?

[image]

Does anyone understand why it keeps saying that it can't find `JRE_HOME`?

**Edit:** My path variable is:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The setup.py contains:

```
jdk_home = environ.get('JDK_HOME')
if not jdk_home:
    jdk_home = subprocess.Popen('readlink -f /usr/bin/javac | sed "s:bin/javac::"',
            shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0].strip()
if not jdk_home:
    raise Exception('Unable to determine JDK_HOME')

jre_home = environ.get('JRE_HOME')
if not jre_home:
    jre_home = subprocess.Popen('readlink -f /usr/bin/java | sed "s:bin/java::"',
            shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0].strip()
if not jre_home:
    raise Exception('Unable to determine JRE_HOME')
```

Somehow you pass the first error check `Unable to determine JDK_HOME`
start a new cmd window and try again.

Write a small code where you test these:

```
import os
print os.environ.get('JDK_HOME')
print os.environ.get('JRE_HOME')
```

They are not case sensitive I tested it.

**EDIT:** Check the environment variables:

```
import json, os
print json.dumps(dict(os.environ), indent = 2)
```

Comment: So bizzare. They both return None. Thanks for the reply though, ill keep checking

Comment: do you export the JRE_HOME variable or just set it temporarily?

Comment: I set them through right clicking on my computer and going to system variables

Comment: that is great, do a restart or at least restart cmd. For me they are visible.

Comment: silly me. a restart worked! Thanks! Its good to note that I could see them when i restarted the CMD. But only could see them from that python script after I restarted the computer

Answer (score -1):

Go to Control Panel Search For Advance System Settings under Environment variables 
ADD a new Environment variable and set it equal to Your path i.e
 Name:JDK_HOME(Same you did for using python on cmd)
 Path: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131
save and restrart cmd and pip install

This worked for me :)