# how to install sikuli in 64 bit windows 7

Tags: python

I have tried to install `sikuli` in my windows PC 64 bit OS through pip.

```
pip install sikuli 
Error: install pyjnius
```

I downloaded the `pyjnius` code and run

```
python setup.py install 

JRE_HOME not found on pip jnius installation
Even after restarting I am facing the same Issue. 
 1. JRE_HOME Set in Ev path and separate variable assigned. 
 2. echo %JRE_HOME% shows correct path
 3. Still when I tried to install pyjnius it shows JRE_HOME not found. 

E:\OPM_Automation\Sikuli_manualDownload\pyjnius-master>python setup.py install
'readlink' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 113, in <module>
    raise Exception('Unable to determine JRE_HOME')
Exception: Unable to determine JRE_HOME
```

Please help. I need to install `Sikuli` in my window to use them with `jython` to automate some desktop application.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38686809/jre-home-not-found-on-pip-jnius-installation

Comment: I have followed the this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38686809/jre-home-not-found-on-pip-jnius-installation .