# Unable to determine JRE_HOME in pyjnius installation

Tags: java, python, python-3.x, pyjnius

I referred from this question: [JRE_HOME not found on pip jnius installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38686809/jre-home-not-found-on-pip-jnius-installation)

However, I tried restarting my computer and reinstalling the JDK and already set my environment variables

These are my environment variables:
This is in the user variables

[uservariables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kBgXS.png)

and I did the same to system variables:

[systemvariables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XD1ZH.png)

I also added it to my path:

[pathvariable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Ouv5.png)

However when I run:

```
python -m pip install pyjnius
```

I get this error:
[errormessage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/haeZP.png)

I also tried verifying it using this script:

```
import os
jdk = os.environ.get('JDK_HOME')
print(jdk)
jre = os.environ.get('JRE_HOME')
print(jre)
```

and it does not return as None. 
Any help on fixing this? And by the way, I am running this on a venv.

EDIT: This is my full environment variables:

[jdk_home in user variables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q2SgL.png)

[path variable in user variables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7sf9V.png)

[jdk_home in system variables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2R9Pp.png)

[path variable in system variables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a0otj.png)

Comment: You have set the env and path variables in the wrong place. look at this [Installation for Windows](https://pyjnius.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html#installation-for-windows)

Comment: I already followed the instructions there but the jre folder is no longer under the jdk folder as of the current version so I specified the folder where it is installed

Comment: But i'll try resetting my variables

Comment: Did you install Cython before?

Comment: yes I have it installed

Comment: Tried resetting my variables but it still throws me the same error

Comment: Edit your question and paste full env/user variables and path please.

Comment: I made the edit to the answer

Comment: Try to follow this: [install](https://github.com/kivy/pyjnius/issues/57#issuecomment-227886988)

Comment: I followed it but it still returns the same error

Comment: observing from the setup.py, it  seems that the name of the variable should be 'jre' instead of 'JRE_HOME'?

Comment: Should I just use the general gps.py facade? because it seems that I can just extract the info that I need from there